# Trouble undestanding this piece of code from codeAcademy Java methods

Tags: java

Can someone please explain to me why in `withdraw()` it needs to add a `return`, but in `deposit()` it doesnt need it?

```
public class SavingsAccount {
  
  int balance;
  
  public SavingsAccount(int initialBalance){
    balance = initialBalance;
  }
  
  public void checkBalance(){
    System.out.println("Hello!");
    System.out.println("Your balance is " + balance);

  }

  public void deposit(int amountToDeposit){
    balance = balance + amountToDeposit;
    System.out.println("You just deposited " + amountToDeposit); 

  }

  public int withdraw(int amountToWithdraw){
    balance = balance - amountToWithdraw;
    System.out.println("You just withdrew " + amountToWithdraw);
    return amountToWithdraw;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount(2000);
    

    //Withdrawing:
    savings.withdraw(150);
    
    //Deposit:
    savings.deposit(25);
    
    //Check balance:
    savings.checkBalance();
    
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` keyword means "give this value back to the caller".

`withdraw()` gives the caller back an `int`, `deposit()` gives the caller back nothing. Since `deposit()` doesn't give any info back to the caller, it doesn't `return` anything. You can see this in the *function signature* - `deposit()` has  *return type* `void`, while `withdraw()` has *return type* `int`

Answer (score 1):

That is because in the definition of your `withdraw()` method, it is stated that it should return an int.
In the `deposit()` method you use void as a return type. When using void, no `return` is needed. (But you could still also just use an empty `return;` at the end of the method if you want to)